# How do I create a t x nk matrix file for Gauss

Tags: r, gauss

I would like to use a panel data econometric test that is implemented in the Gauss statistical software. With the R package `MASS::write.matrix` I have managed to generate an ASCII file and read the file from within Gauss. This worked well for t x n matrix. But I'm wondering how to export a t x nk matrix. Would the nk columns simply be appended to one another?

Comment: There is a `write.matrix` function in the recommended MASS package. Could also have coerced to dataframe and used `write.table`.

Answer (score 0):

Using an example dataset from the plm package, here is how you could reshape the dataset in a t x nk matrix format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(plm) # For the example dataset
data("Produc", package = "plm")
spreadvariable <- c("pcap", "pc", "emp", "unemp")
gaussmatrixfile <- file.path(tempdir(),"gaussmatrix.prn")
gaussmatrixfile
Produc %>%
    select_("year", "state", .dots = spreadvariable) %>% 
    gather(variable, value, -year,-state) %>%
    unite(state_variable, state, variable) %>%
    spread(state_variable, value) %>%
    MASS::write.matrix(gaussmatrixfile)
```

This file can then be read from Gauss with

```
load datax[t,n*k+1]     = gaussmatrix.prn;        /* t x nk matrix */
/* Remove the first column with years*/
x = datax[.,2:cols(datax)];
```